# ListView Change background of single item

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, listview

Let's assume I have the following listview:

```
<ListView Name="list" />
```

and the following code inside my function:

```
list.Items.Add("red");
list.Items.Add("green");
```

How can I change the background of the first item to red and second one to green?

Comment: How about creating a "ColorViewModel" class with a "BackgroundColor" property? list.Items.Add(new ColorViewModel("red", Colors.Red)); And then bind listitems' "Background" property to your viewmodel's "BackgroundColor"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `ItemContainerStyle` to define a style for the items.

In the style you can bind the `Background` property to the item itself which is representation of the color.

Now the implicit color converter will convert to appropriate color and set to the background property.

example

```
<ListView Name="list" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

result

[image: result]

**Alternate approch**

here is how you can use `Triggers` to set the values conditionally

I used `DataTrigger` to see if the item meet my condition and then I can set the desired color via a setter

```
<ListView Name="list">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}"
                             Value="red">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}"
                             Value="mygreen">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

result

[image: result]

in above example you can see that the background color is only applied to only desired items eg. red & mygreen

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite exactly what I was looking for. For example when I add an item with the name mygreen I cannot change the background anymore.